# Progress Indicator to map scores in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase

I need to implement a progress bar indicator which shows the scores achieved by the user in games. How can we implement such progress indicator in Android? Is there any library that can be used in android studio to achieve the results below?

[image: Progress Bar mapping scores of games[1]]

Comment: post your database under your question.

Comment: Also improve the question, or someone will down vote.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. Also take a look at [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: creating a progress bar is a trivial task. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this lib [SegmentedProgressBar](https://github.com/carlosmuvi/SegmentedProgressBar?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=5971)